# Android Studio fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a quiz app with a sidebar that consists of flags (image buttons), and when you click on each flag, you can type in the country it belongs to in a fragment on the right hand side of the screen. However I'm getting an error inside the if statement in my Play.java file where it says:

fragment = new FragmentOne();

and

fragment = new FragmentTwo();

**Play.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;                                                           
import android.app.FragmentManager;                                                 
import android.view.View;                                                           
import android.view.Menu;                                                           
import android.app.Activity;                                                        
import android.app.Fragment;                                                        
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;                                             

import layout.FragmentOne;                                                          
import layout.FragmentTwo;                                                          


public class Play extends MainActivity {                                            

Fragment fragment;                                                              


@Override                                                                       
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                            
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                         
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);                                     

}                                                                               

public void ChangeFragment(View view) {                                         


    if(view == findViewById(R.id.imageButton10)) {                              
        fragment = new FragmentOne();                                           
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();                              
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();                         
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);                              
        ft.commit();                                                            
    }                                                                           
    if(view == findViewById(R.id.imageButton9))  {                              
        fragment = new FragmentTwo();                                           
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();                              
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();                         
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);                              
        ft.commit();                                                            
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               

}
```

**activity_play.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_play"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.karolinawullum.quizapp.Play">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1">


        <TextView
            android:text="Which country does this flag belong to? Press flag    to answer."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/germany"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:onClick="ChangeFragment" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/greece"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="ChangeFragment"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/france"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/finland"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/denmark"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cyprus"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/belgium"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/austria"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="layout.FragmentOne"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_weight="0.72" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
package layout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
}



}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: You need to add an empty constructor in your fragment class.

Comment: The error I get is: "Incompatible types: required: android.app.Fragment, found: layout.FragmentOne"

Comment: @KaraW In your Play.java you import `import android.app.Fragment;` but in FragmentOne    you import `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`.

Comment: Remove the `layout.FragmentOne` and `layout.FragmentTwo`imports. You need to import the class and not the layout. Also as @Tristan suggested in his answer, your imports are different. Make them same

Comment: Changed the fragment variable type as explained by @Tristan, and Play.java runs and displays the flags, but nothing happens as I click on them. Aka fragment doesn't show

Comment: @PrerakSola, I get errors when removing layout.FragmentOne and layout.FragmentTwoimports. How do I import the classes instead?

Comment: @Kara W do not remove the imports, you need them. As of your fragment not being displayed, that's a totally different issue you'll have to debug :)

Comment: Ah my mistake. I didn't see that your package name is layout. The imports are correct as per that.

Comment: @Kara W Here is an hint on your fragment not being displayed issue.You are mixing and confusing the two ways of adding fragments (xml way VS code way). Read the doc

Comment: @TristanFrascari thanks for your help so far! A bit unsure about the difference - would you mind explaining further what I should be looking at? does it have anything to do with onClick?

Comment: @KaraW Sure, take a look at this documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions you will see that `FragmentTransaction.replace()` takes a container id (in other terms a `ViewGroup` id) in parameter, though you're giving it the id of a `fragment` xml component. Replace your `fragment` in your xml by `Viewgroup` (`LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout` etc...). Of course, you'll have to add a piece of code to load the first fragment in `onCreate` programmatically.

Comment: @TristanFrascari Im very new at this, could you please inform me what code should be added in onCreate?

Comment: @KaraW look a this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding the programmatically part.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Play.java` class, your `Fragment` variable is of type `android.app.Fragment`. Though your `FragmentOne.java` (and I assume your FragmentTwo.java as well) class is of type `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

So in your `Play.java` class you're trying to initialize the Fragment variable with the `wrong type`.

Either :

- Make your `FragmentOne.java` and `FragmentTwo.java` extends `android.app.Fragment` instead of the support version one
- Make your `Fragment` variable in `Play.java` of type `android.support.v4.Fragment` by changing your import.